# How do i configure external service call certificates in Jboss 5

Tags: keystore, jboss5.x, sslhandshakeexception

When trying to connect the external service from plain java code i am getting proper response. I am using Java 1.8.51. For setting the certificate in plain java code i am using the below property,

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", path);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", password);
```

By using the same code while connecting external service from JBoss 5 i getting the below exception,

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:543)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:492)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:436)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:421)
    at com.intuit.ds.dash.som.helper.customercentral.CustomerCentralService_old.getResponseFromCC(CustomerCentralService_old.java:185)
    at com.intuit.ds.dash.som.helper.customercentral.CustomerCentralService_old.main(CustomerCentralService_old.java:284)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpConnection.onSendAfterWrite(CommonsHttpConnection.java:112)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:47)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:622)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:585)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding the below properties in JAVAOPTS in run.bat (for windows), run.sh for ( linux),

```
For Windows run.bat
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="keystorepath" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="password"

    For Linux run.sh

    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystorepath -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password"
```